# Find closed form solution using generation function for the binomial coefficients

Tags: binomial-coefficients, generating-functions

I don't have any idea how to start this problem. Could you give a hint?

Find closed form solution using generation function for the binomial coefficients:

$$a_n:=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}^2(-1)^k$$

Comment: Show that $a_n=0$ when $n$ is odd, and $(-1)^n \binom{2 n}{n}$ when n is even.  The resulting series expansion may look familiar to you.

Comment: I could get for odd case,  but cannot get for even case.  Can you help me,  please?

Comment: $$\sum_{k=0}^n{n\choose k}^2={2n\choose n}=\frac{(2n)!}{n!^2}$$

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Note that:  $a_n=\sum_{k \geq 0} \binom{n}{k}^2(-1)^k=\sum_{k \geq 0} \binom{n}{k} (-1)^k \times\binom{n}{n-k}  $, since $\binom{n}{n-k}=\binom{n}{k}$, this is readily a [convolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product) (of the coefficients of $(1-x)^n$ and the coefficients of $(1+x)^n$).

Looking closely, this is $$a_n=[x^n]\left\{(1-x)^n (1+x)^n\right\} = [x^n]\left\{(1-x^2)^n\right\}$$

Thus it follows that if $n$ is *odd*, then $a_n = 0$, because $(1-x^2)^n$ has only even powers of $x$. And, if $n$ is *even*, then $a_n = \binom{n}{n/2} (-1)^{n/2}$ by the Binomial Theorem.

**Notation:** $[x^n]\left\{p(x)\right\}$ denotes the coefficient of $x^n$ in $p(x)$.

Answer (score 4):

This is one of these hypergeometric sums where it is not easy to make progress without using Sister Celine's method / Zeilberger's algorithm, which is not difficult to implement, at least in its basic form.

This algorithm produces the following recurrence for your sum:
$$n a_n+4(n-1) a_{n-2} = 0.$$
Note that we have $a_0=1$ and $a_1=0.$

Re-write the recurrence so that it becomes apparent that it produces a product:
$$a_n = -4\frac{n-1}{n} a_{n-2}.$$

This implies that for $n$ odd, we have $a_n = 0,$ and for $n$ even, we have
$$a_n = (-4)^{n/2} \prod_{k=1}^{n/2} \frac{2k-1}{2k}
= (-4)^{n/2} \prod_{k=1}^{n/2} \frac{(2k-1)2k}{(2k)^2}
= (-4)^{n/2} n! \frac{1}{4^{n/2}} \prod_{k=1}^{n/2} \frac{1}{k^2}\\
= (-1)^{n/2} \frac{n!}{(n/2)!^2} = (-1)^{n/2} {n\choose n/2}.$$

Now the generating function of the central binomial coefficients is well known and given by
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4z}}
=\sum_{n\ge 0} {2n\choose n} z^n.$$
To match up the coefficient $z^n$ with ${n\choose n/2}$ we evidently have to replace $z$ by $z^2$ in this generating function (which also has the nice effect of producing zero values for odd indices of $a_n$ as required), getting
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4z^2}}
=\sum_{n\ge 0} {2n\choose n} z^{2n}.$$
Finally add in the sign, noting that $i^{2n} = (-1)^n,$ where $i$ is the imaginary unit, for the end result
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4(iz)^2}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+4z^2}}.$$
**Addendum.** In order to verify the recurrence put 
$$F_{n,j} = (-1)^j {n\choose j}^2$$
and check that
$$F_{n,j}\frac{n}{n-1} - (F_{n-1,j}-F_{n-1,j-1}) \frac{2n-1}{n-1}
+ (F_{n-2, j} +2 F_{n-2,j-1} + F_{n-2,j-2}) = 0.$$
This equation is the output from Sister Celine. Now adding over $j$ this becomes
$$a_n\frac{n}{n-1} - (a_{n-1}-a_{n-1}) \frac{2n-1}{n-1}
+ (a_{n-2} +2 a_{n-2} + a_{n-2}) = 0$$
which is
$$a_n\frac{n}{n-1} + 4 a_{n-2} =0,$$
precisely the recurrence we are trying to verify.

Comment: I don't know how I could have overlooked the convolution hiding in plain sight here. Upvoting the convolution answer.

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert #1 \right\vert}%
 \newcommand{\yy}{\Longleftrightarrow}$
$\ds{%
a_{n} \equiv \sum_{k = 0}^{n}{n \choose k}^{2}\pars{-1}^{k}: {\large ?}}$

> \begin{align}
> a_{n} &= \sum_{k = 0}^{n}{n \choose k}\pars{-1}^{k}
> \sum_{\ell = 0}^{n}{n \choose \ell}\delta_{\ell, k}
> =
> \sum_{k = 0}^{n}{n \choose k}\pars{-1}^{k}
> \sum_{\ell = 0}^{n}{n \choose \ell}\oint_{\verts{z} = 1}{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}\,
> {1 \over z^{\ell - k + 1}}
> \\[3mm]&=
> \oint_{\verts{z} = 1}{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}\,{1 \over z}
> \sum_{k = 0}^{n}{n \choose k}\pars{-z}^{k}
> \sum_{\ell = 0}^{n}{n \choose \ell}\pars{1 \over z}^{\ell}
> =
> \oint_{\verts{z} = 1}{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}\,{1 \over z}\,\pars{1 - z}^{n}
> \pars{1 + {1 \over z}}^{n}
> \\[3mm]&=
> \oint_{\verts{z} = 1}{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}\,{1 \over z^{n + 1}}\,\pars{1 - z^{2}}^{n}
> =
> \oint_{\verts{z} = 1}{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}\,{1 \over z^{n + 1}}
> \sum_{\ell = 0}^{n}{n \choose \ell}\pars{-z^{2}}^{\ell}
> \\[3mm]&=
> \sum_{\ell = 0}^{n}{n \choose \ell}\pars{-1}^{\ell}
> \oint_{\verts{z} = 1}{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}\,{1 \over z^{n - 2\ell + 1}}
> =
> \left\lbrace%
> \begin{array}{ccl}
> 0 & \quad\mbox{if} & n\,\,\,\mbox{is}\,\,\,{\it odd}
> \\[2mm]
> \pars{-1}^{n/2}{n \choose {n \over 2}} & \quad\mbox{if}
> & n\,\,\,\mbox{is}\,\,\,{\it even} 
> \end{array}\right.
> \end{align}

$$\color{#0000ff}{\large%
\sum_{k = 0}^{n}{n \choose k}^{2}\pars{-1}^{k}
=
\left\lbrace%
\begin{array}{ccl}
0 & \quad\mbox{if} & n\,\,\,\mbox{is}\,\,\,{\it odd}
\\[2mm]
\pars{-1}^{n/2}{n \choose {n \over 2}} & \quad\mbox{if}
& n\,\,\,\mbox{is}\,\,\,{\it even} 
\end{array}\right.}
$$

Comment: Very nice technique.

Comment: @MarkoRiedel It's always straightforward. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Let define $$a_n=\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}^2=\sum_{k=0}^n t_k.$$
Observing the ratio
$$
\frac{t_{k+1}}{t_k}=\frac{(-1)^{k+1}\binom{n}{k+1}^2}{(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}^2}=-\frac{(k-n)^2}{(k+1)^2}=\frac{(k-n)(k-n)}{(k+1)(k+1)}(-1)
$$
we see that $a_n$ can be expressed with the hypergeometric function $_2F_1$ as 
$$
a_n=\;_2F_1\left(\matrix{-n,\;-n\\1}\Bigg|-1\right).
$$

Using the Kummer's identity  for $b-a+c=1$ and $b$ negative integer 
$$ _2F_1\left(\matrix{a,\;b\\c}\Bigg|-1\right)=2\cos\left(\tfrac{\pi b}{2}\right) \frac{\Gamma(|b|)\Gamma(b-a+1)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{|b|}{2}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{b}{2}-a+1\right)}
 $$
one has
$$
a_n
=2\cos\left(\tfrac{\pi n}{2}\right) \frac{\Gamma(n)}{\Gamma\left(\tfrac{n}{2}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{n}{2}+1\right)}
$$
and observing that
$$
\frac{\Gamma(n)}{\Gamma\left(\tfrac{n}{2}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{n}{2}+1\right)}
=\frac{(n-1)!}{(n/2-1)!(n/2)!}=\frac{n/2}{n}\frac{n!}{(n/2)!(n/2)!}
=\frac{1}{2}\binom{n}{n/2}
$$
we obtain finally

> $$
> a_n=\frac{(-1)^{n/2}\left[1+(-1)^n\right]}{2}\binom{n}{n/2}
> $$

Comment: But, when `n` is odd, you answer is not 0 as expected.

Comment: when $n$ is odd $(-1)^n=-1$ so $1+(-1)^n=0$ and $a_n=0$. When $n$ is even $(-1)^n=1$ so $1+(-1)^n=2$ and $a_n=(-1)^{n/2}\binom{n}{n/2}$, or if you prefer,putting $n=2\nu$, $a_{2\nu}=(-1)^{\nu}\binom{2\nu}{\nu}$.